# Webpack: apply `ts-loader` to Vue files only

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader, ts-loader

I'm working on a large project with a bit of Vue in it. We're starting to add TypeScript incrementally.

We can't yet add `ts-loader` to the project, as that gives 2000+ errors. However, if we add type annotations to Vue SFCs without `ts-loader`, `vue-loader` can't process the syntax.

My idea was to use `ts-loader` on Vue files only, but I can't get the Webpack config to work.

I've tried multiple approaches so far, and I feel like at least one of them must work, if I can get the syntax right. Code extracts from webpack.base.conf.js:

**Forcing only Vue files to be processed with include/exclude rules**
I've tried many variants of include/exclude

```
rules: [
  [ eslint-loader ],
  [ vue-loader ],
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
    exclude: /src/,
    include: /src\/components\/vue/,
  },
  [ babel-loader ],
  [ other standard loaders ],
]
```

**Adding `ts-loader` to `vue-loader` options**

```
vueLoaderConfig = {
  ...[existing CSS loaders],
 loader: 'ts-loader',
};

// relevant part of config object

rules: [
  [ eslint-loader ],
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: vueLoaderConfig,
  },
  [ babel-loader ],
  [ other standard loaders ],
]
```

**Renaming .vue files to `.vue.ts` to target with Webpack rule**

```
rules: [
  [ eslint-loader ],
  {
    test: /\.vue\.ts$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: vueLoaderConfig,
  },
  {
    test: /\.vue\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
  },
  [ babel-loader ],
  [ other standard loaders ],
]
```

---

Should any of the above configs actually work? Can you see any obvious places I'm getting the format wrong? If anyone has a totally different approach, I'd be interested in hearing that too.

---

Versions:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"ts-loader": "^5.3.1",
"typescript": "^3.1.6",
"vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
"webpack": "^4.25.1",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```